Error: Exception in HostFunction: TypeError: expected dynamic type `boolean', but had type `object'
I'm encountering a TypeError in my code that reads:
Exception in HostFunction: TypeError: expected dynamic type 'boolean', but had type 'object'
I am using  React Native, JavaScript and this error occurs when I type the password in the text input
when I start typing a number after a special character it crashes
I am using supabase for Auth
The code:
<TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='Password'
                    value={password}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={(value)=> setPassword(value)
                    }/>


            <TouchableOpacity style={[{backgroundColor:"black", borderRadius: 5,},(email.length==0||password.length<7) && {opacity:.5} ]} 
            disabled={email.length==0||password.length<7 ||{loading}}
            onPress={()=>signInWithEmail()}  >
              <Text style={{color:"white", padding:10,textAlign:"center"}}>Login</Text>
          
            </TouchableOpacity>


you should give us more code about text input function on change text or related function/values

added the code which i had written

what is type of password?

string after i enter a special character like # or @  and i enter a number it crashes
